# How to make fit size only for Image in UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, image, uiwebview

I loaded `HTML` to my `UIWebView` that including both `Text` and `Images`.

`Text` is fit to `UIWebView` and `Images` are not fit to `UIWebView`.

It's too large in `UIWebView`.

It's showing scroll bar at the end of the `UIWebView`.

I want to adjust image fit size in UWebView. So i tested with following codes.

```
self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

However it's fixed including Text and Text is too small to read and Images are fixed.

I want to set Text Normally and only want to fit size Image in `UIWeView`.

How can i do it?

Comment: Did u solve your problem? I have the same issue?

Answer (score 10):

I have solve this problem using css. The css contained within the style tags below will make sure to automatically resize your images maintaining aspect ratio for the width of the UIWebView. Hope this helps!

```
NSString *strTemplateHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>img{max-width:100%%;height:auto !important;width:auto !important;};</style></head><body style='margin:0; padding:0;'>%@</body></html>", @"insert your html content here"];

[webView loadHTMLString:strTemplateHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Its working as expected, after adding the `<style>img{max-width:100%%;height:auto !important;width:auto !important;};</style>` code the maximum image width is lesser than or equal to the webview width

Answer (score 5):

Use the viewport meta tag is used by UIWebView on the iPhone/iPad to determine how to display a web page.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

refer below link for more details:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: I am using HTML with NSString like that <html><head><body>%@</body></head></html>.Where to i put these code?

Comment: add in head tag <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
    
</head>
<body>
</body>

Comment: yes i added like you said , However it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet may help you

```
NSString *fontString = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html>\
    <head>\
    <style>\
    img{";
        NSString *imageDimensionsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"max-width: %fpx; max-height: %fpx;}",self.view.frame.size.width - 50.0f, self.view.frame.size.height/2];
        fontString =[fontString stringByAppendingString:imageDimensionsStr];
fontString = [fontString stringByAppendingString:@"</style></head><body>"];
    fontString = [[fontString stringByAppendingString:htmlString] stringByAppendingString:@"</body></html>"];
    [webView loadHTMLString:fontString baseURL:nil];
```

The above code will resize the width and height of the image according to view dimension. You can change according to your requirement.